# SRAM Cassette on Campy Wheels

Tags: hub, cassette, sram, campagnolo

I wrecked my current wheel set in a crash and am considering purchasing a set of Campy Hyperons from a friend. AFAIK the wheels are stock and haven't been tweaked in any way.

I would like to know if I can use my current SRAM PG 1071 cassette with these wheels or if I'll need to also buy a new cassette to play nice with the Campy hub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Campagnolo wheels are available with both Shimano/SRAM and Campagnolo cassette compatible freewheel bodies. Ask which cassette your friend has and if they have Campagnolo, you can get the correct freehub body as a spare part.

SRAM/Shimano and Campagnolo cassettes have slightly different cog spacing. You can mix them, but the derailleur adjustment will be slightly off.

Comment: I think it isn't just "adjustment" but the derailer "pull" – I don't think you'd be able to adjust a SRAM/Shimano derailer to play nicely (perfectly) with a Campy cassette or vice versa.

Comment: The width difference between Shimano and Campy cassettes is 1.6mm. If you adjust the derailer for center cogs and the smallest and largest cogs with limit screws, the next ones will be misadjusted by about 0.7mm.